# R select data frame rows using NA in search pattern

Tags: r, dataframe

I wish to select row indexes from a source data frame given search criteria in a search pattern data frame. For simplicity and clarity, the colnames in the search pattern data frame must be a subset of those in the source data frame. But here is the kicker - both data frames can include NA's and I need to use those NA's in the search criteria so excluding those records beforehand will not fulfill my goal.

I'm including a working solution to my challenge but am interested to see if anyone has suggestions for improvements. I've done it using just base R, which is my preference, but if anyone has a quick *that's already done in this package* tip, I'd be grateful.

In my real situation my search pattern data frame can comprise 20k records and the data frame being searched is >500k records. Under this situation the run time can be >20 mins, which is unfortunate. thanks

```
selectRows <- function(df.pattern, df.x){
    output <- lapply(1:nrow(df.pattern), function(i){
        x <- df.pattern[i,]
        
        res <- lapply(colnames(x), function(col){
            if(is.na(x[,col])){
                which(is.na(df.x[,col]))
            }else{
                grep(x[,col], df.x[,col])
            }
        })
        
    index.select <- Reduce(intersect, res)
    index.select
    })#END lapply
    
    output
}#END selectRows



#df.x is the data frame to search
df.x <- expand.grid(a=1:10, b=letters, c=LETTERS, stringsAsFactors = F)
#replace some cells with NA
for(i in 1:3) df.x[i,i ] <- NA
head(df.x)

#for simplicity the search pattern df is taken from the original df, using rows with NA's and complete cases too 
df.pattern <- df.x[c(22,1:4,10),c(2,1,3)]
row.names(df.pattern) <- NULL
df.pattern

results <- selectRows(df.pattern, df.x)
unlist(results)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem, it seems that the output is always the row names (as numbers) of `df.pattern`. I'm sure I'm missing something...

Comment: if you were to reset the row numbers in df.pattern `row.names(df.pattern) <- NULL` , then hopefully you'll see it's returning the row index of df.x.  But @akrun nailed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use `inner_join`.  Create a column of row sequence, then join with the 'df.pattern' and `pull` the sequence vector

```
library(dplyr)
df.x %>% 
    mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
    inner_join(df.pattern, .) %>%
    pull(rn)
#[1] 22  1  2  3  4 10
```

---

Or `paste` the rows to a single string, create a logical vector with `%in%`, get the positions with `which`

```
which(do.call(paste, df.x) %in% do.call(paste, df.pattern[names(df.x)]))
#[1]  1  2  3  4 10 22
```

If the order needs to be based on the second dataset and the second data doesn't need to consider duplicate matches, use `match`

```
match(do.call(paste, df.pattern[names(df.x)]), do.call(paste, df.x))
[1] 22  1  2  3  4 10
```

---

Or a use a data.table join

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df.x)[, rn := .I][df.pattern, rn, on = names(df.pattern)]
#[1] 22  1  2  3  4 10
```

Comment: I added two code edits. First, I rearranged the columns so that the order in `df.pattern` is not the same order as in `df.x` and all three solutions still work.  But then I changed the row order in `df.pattern`  (`df.pattern <- df.x[c(22,1:4,10),c(2,1,3)]`), in this case now only the third suggestion using `data.table` gives results in an order matching `df.pattern`

Comment: @mfolkes  In the update you showed, it is changing the column order, which was not taken into account in second solution i.e. `c(2, 1, 3)`.  For that you need to have the same column order i.e. `which(do.call(paste, df.x) %in% do.call(paste, df.pattern[names(df.x)]))`

Comment: @mfolkes regarding the first solution, it returns the same index but in an ordered way ie. .I get `[1]  1  2  3  4 10 22` where as you get `selectRows(df.pattern, df.x) %>% unlist#
[1] 22  1  2  3  4 10` or in second solution `which(do.call(paste, df.x) %in% do.call(paste, df.pattern[names(df.x)]))#[1]  1  2  3  4 10 22`

Comment: @mfolkes If you want the order from second dataset, change the argument order in `inner_join` i..e `%>% inner_join(df.pattern, .) %>% pull(rn)#[1] 22  1  2  3  4 10`

Comment: these are all excellent comments. I acknowledge that you did answer my first post as needed.  And I really appreciate your additions. A little bit of vectorizing does wonders. Thanks very much.